# How to check if the element is not the first-child?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

How do you know if the current element is not the first-child?

It should work with `$(this)`, for example:

```
$("li").click(function(e) {
    if (/* $(this) is not the first-child */)
    {
        /* do something */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can do this just to test an element if it's the first child: `$(this).is(':first-child')`. Other selectors like `:last-child` would work too.

Comment: That will return `true` for everything...  `:first` would check that it is the first item in the jQuery set, I believe you might want `:first-child`

Comment: Also, `.not(':first-child')` will still return a jQuery set, not a boolean... `.is(':not(:first-child)')`....

Comment: This solution is returning if the element "is" the first-child when @WorkingHard asked for knowing when "is not" the first-child. Not mentioning that basically all the answer was giving away by @gnarf. I would have liked that @gnarf answered this, and that SO users didn't have voted for a wrong answer (It had at least 3 points when it was all wrong).

Comment: Turning it into "is not" is a matter of adding the `!` operator.

Comment: *shrug* I commented so that he could make his answer better (or at least correct ;) )

Comment: Btw, this intersects the current result set against **ALL** first child elements in the document :)

Answer (score 30):

You could simply ask for its `.index()` position (relative to its siblings).

```
$(this).index();   // returns a zero based index position
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, `.index()` will return `0` for the first child, which is false, and anything else is true, so therefore, `.index()` actually will return true for anything but the first child...  Perfect answer

Comment: I think it's more of a side-effect of .index(), but nice observation indeed.

Comment: Not sure if i'm seeing a bug in jQuery, but I have something that does parentDiv.parent('td') which I can see in firebug contains 1 element. parentDiv.parent('td').size() is 1, but parentDiv.parent('td').index() returns -1 . Anyone know why?

Comment: This is a really great way to test if the item is not first. thanks! if ( $(this).index() ) { //then it is not first }

Answer (score 12):

For all `li`'s in `#thing` that aren't first child:

```
$('#thing li:not(:first-child)')
```

see http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can check if `$(this).prev().length` is defined, like in:

```
if (!$(this).prev().length){ //This means $(this is the first child
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Very good I think most readable and matches other implementation of mine. Alternative to length use .size()

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to select everything except the first child, this is how to do it:

```
$('#some-parent').children().not(':first')
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the index

```
$(this).index() == 0 // is first
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple, use the DOM

```
$("li").click(function(e) {

    if (this.previousSibling != null)
    {
        /* do something */
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who want a vanilla JS solution:

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-1"></div>
  <div id="child-2"></div>
  <div id="child-3"></div>
</div>
```

```js
let element = document.getElementById('child-1');
console.log(element.parentElement.firstElementChild === element); // true
console.log(element.parentElement.lastElementChild === element);  // false

element = document.getElementById('child-2');
console.log(element.parentElement.firstElementChild === element); // false
console.log(element.parentElement.lastElementChild === element);  // false

element = document.getElementById('child-3');
console.log(element.parentElement.firstElementChild === element); // false
console.log(element.parentElement.lastElementChild === element);  // true
```

It's not the most elegant thing but it gets the job done.

You can even check if it's the nth element in the same fashion.

```js
let n = 2; // check if it's the 2nd child

let element = document.getElementById('child-2');
// index starts at 0
console.log(element.parentElement.children[-1 + n] === element); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(this).not(':first');
```

Comment: `:first` is not the same as `:first-child`, and using `.not(':first')` will *remove* the `:first` item from the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").click(function(e) {
   if ($(this).index != 0 )
  {
      /* do something */
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A less complex (IE 9 compatible) pure/vanilla JavaScript way to achieve this is to use the `matches` function of `Element`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Example:

```js
console.log( document.querySelectoer( '#my-div' ).matches( ':first-child' ) ); // true or false
```