# Slider not working properly at the last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently learning Jquery and I'm a total newbie. Currently I was trying to make this custom slider work. [image: the image] What I am trying to achieve is, when someone clicks the `prev` or `next` buttons , nothing happens to the slider but the text written above it changes, i.e goes to the next `<li>` element. I wrote some code and it is working fine, but the problem comes when the slider is on the last child. When I click the next button the text disappears and now I cant even go back. I am pasting all the code I wrote here any help would be greatly appreciated and would help me to learn. THANKS A LOT!

#### HTML

```
<ul class="testimonial-text">
  <li class="test-current">
    <p>“Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

    <h4>Michel Buble &amp; Tinta turner</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>“Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

    <h4>Rick Armstrong &amp; Ashley Tist</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>“Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

    <h4>Mike Tran &amp; Kimse Tricks</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>“Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

    <h4>Michel Buble &amp; Tinta turner</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>“Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

    <h4>Michel Buble &amp; Tinta turner</h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the buttons

```
<a class="testimonials-prev" ></a>
<a class="testimonials-next" ></a>
```

#### CSS

```
ul.testimonial-text{
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
ul.testimonial-text li{
display: none;
}
ul.testimonial-text li.test-current{
  display: block;
}
ul.testimonial-text li p{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #7c7c7c;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
ul.testimonial-text li h4{
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}
ul.testimonial-images{
  list-style: none;
}
ul.testimonial-images li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 16px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
ul.testimonial-images li:first-child{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
a.testimonials-prev{
  background: url('../images/icons/test-icons.png') no-repeat;
  height: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.testimonials-next{
  background: url('../images/icons/test-icons.png') no-repeat top right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### JQUERY / JAVASCRIPT

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("a.testimonials-next").click(function() {
  $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").next().fadeIn('slow');
    $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").next().addClass('test-current');
    $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current:first").removeClass('test-current');
});

  });
$("a.testimonials-prev").click(function() {
  $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").prev().fadeIn('slow');
    $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").prev().addClass('test-current');
    $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current:last").removeClass('test-current');
});

});

});

</script>
```

I'm very sorry if the code is sloppy. Thanks alot!

Comment: You also are probably gonna run into a problem from what I've seen with if a user clicks the next or prev button rapidly. It will cause strange behaviour. Unless, you've already accounted for it and just didn't put the code in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add an if statement before the fade that would check to see if the li is the first one? (you would do similar for the next button as well).

Here's a JSFiddle working:  http://jsfiddle.net/JUveT/

Example:

```
$("a.testimonials-prev").click(function() {
     if($("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").prev().length){
         $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
         $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").prev().fadeIn('slow');
         $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").prev().addClass('test-current');
         $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current:last").removeClass('test-current');
         });
     }
```

I got the code for the condition from here:

[How to check if the element is not the first-child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676454/how-to-check-if-the-element-is-not-the-first-child)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$("a.testimonials-next").click(function() {
      $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        var index = $("ul.testimonial-text li).index($(this));
        if(index == $("ul.testimonial-text li).length - 1){
            var $next = $("ul.testimonial-text li:first");
        }
        else    {
            var $next = $(this).next();
        }    
        $(this).removeClass('test-current');
        $next.addClass('test-current').fadeIn('slow');
    });

      });

    $("a.testimonials-prev").click(function() {
      $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
         var index = $("ul.testimonial-text li).index($(this));
         if(index == 0){
            var $prev = $("ul.testimonial-text li:last");
        }
        else    {
            var $prev = $(this).prev();
        }  

        $(this).removeClass('test-current');
        $prev.addClass('test-current').fadeIn('slow');
    });

    })
```

;

Answer (score 0):

The script hides the active `li.current-test` regardless if a next/prev element exists. When you reach the last element, a next element naturally does not exist, but the script still hides the current active element regardless. You need to check first if a next element actually exists:

```
$("a.testimonials-next").click(function() {
     // Switch to the next element, if it exists
    if ($("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").next().length) {
        $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").next().fadeIn('slow');
        $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").next().addClass('test-current');
        $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current:first").removeClass('test-current');
    }
});
```

Now, that being said, your code could benefit greatly from assigning jQuery objects to variables and chaining of methods, that would make your code more readable and faster. Consider this snippet in regard to the one above:

```
$("a.testimonials-next").click(function() {
    var current_element = $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current"),
        next_element    = current_element.next();
     // Switch to the next element, if it exists
    if (next_element.length) {
        current_element.removeClass('test-current').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        next_element.addClass('test-current').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ragzor use this code for your problem

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
            ul.testimonial-text{
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
    ul.testimonial-text li{
    display: none;
    }
    ul.testimonial-text li.test-current{
    display: block;
    }
    ul.testimonial-text li p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #7c7c7c;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    ul.testimonial-text li h4{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    }

    ul.testimonial-images{
    list-style: none;
    }
    ul.testimonial-images li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 16px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    }
    ul.testimonial-images li:first-child{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

    a.testimonials-prev{
    background: url('../images/icons/test-icons.png') no-repeat;
    height: 80px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    a.testimonials-next{
    background: url('../images/icons/test-icons.png') no-repeat top right;
    height: 80px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="testimonials-prev" >Prev</a>
       <ul class="testimonial-text">
                    <li class="test-current">
                      <p>1 “Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

                      <h4>Michel Buble &amp; Tinta turner</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <p>2 “Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

                      <h4>Rick Armstrong &amp; Ashley Tist</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <p>3 “Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

                      <h4>Mike Tran &amp; Kimse Tricks</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <p>4 “Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

                      <h4>Michel Buble &amp; Tinta turner</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <p>5 “Sagittis risus nec venenatis. Ut laoreet iaculis massa et feugiat. Cras elementum quamvitae magna as elementum quamvitae magna porttitor in fermentum setlat ul.”</p>

                      <h4>Michel Buble &amp; Tinta turner</h4>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

    <a class="testimonials-next" >Next</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.testimonials-next").click(function() {
          $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            var index = $("ul.testimonial-text li").index($(this));
            if(index == $("ul.testimonial-text li").length - 1){
                var $next = $("ul.testimonial-text li:first");
            }
            else    {
                var $next = $(this).next();
            }    
            $(this).removeClass('test-current');
            $next.addClass('test-current').fadeIn('slow');
        });

          });

        $("a.testimonials-prev").click(function() {
          $("ul.testimonial-text li.test-current").fadeOut('slow', function() {
             var index = $("ul.testimonial-text li").index($(this));
             if(index == 0){
                var $prev = $("ul.testimonial-text li:last");
            }
            else    {
                var $prev = $(this).prev();
            }  

            $(this).removeClass('test-current');
            $prev.addClass('test-current').fadeIn('slow');
        });

        })
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ragzor why don't you use Carousel give [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), its easy, reliable and works perfectly fine. I have used it many times.