# jQuery is(":first") takes no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery is(":first") to judge whether an element is the first in its siblings, but it always return false. Is there any wrong? or is it a bug of jQuery? thx.

```
$(".page:first").is(":first"); //always return false.
```

Comment: You're confusing `:first` with `:first-child`.

Comment: Yes, in CSS you'd be looking at `:first-of-type`

Comment: Share some of the HTML to get a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: see this link it might be help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676454/how-to-check-if-the-element-is-not-the-first-child

Comment: From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/): *"Selects the first matched element."*

Comment: if($(this).is(':first-child'))
{
    alert('123');
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test whether the first found `.page` element is the first sibling you can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
if ($('.page:first').index() == 0) {
    // it's the first child
}
```

Or simply:

```
if ($('.page').index() == 0) {
    // it's the first child
}
```

The `.is()` function works by matching the current result set against the given selector, which is the first element of the document, i.e. `<html>`. Only `$('html').is(':first')` will be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this:

```
$(".page").is(":first") //always return false.
```

Or,

```
$(".page:first") //always return false.
```

Or,

```
$(".page").first() //always return false.
```

Comment: The first (almost always false) is not the same as the other two (result set comprising at most one element).

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the first element of `.page` is the **first element**. According to your code, we cannot know whose element's first child.

If you check output of `$(":first")`, it gives the top element of page which is `<html>` tag.

Therefore, your check will always return false. Specify more about what you want to do or this logic will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a method called `first()`. So try to use `$(".page").first()`